# vue.js keep-alive after page refresh

Tags: routes, vue.js

I'm wondering if/how this is possible.

I have a route that has a bunch of select dropdowns,  atext field or two, etc.  I want to keep these populated with the last selected values when I route back to this view.

If I wrap the router-view in a `<keep-alive>` tag, I'm able to achieve this when navigating to and from the route via `<router-link>` tags.

However if the user is on a route and refreshes the page and then navigates back to the original route with all of the fields, they are lost since keep-alive doesn't deal with page refreshes (unless I'm wrong).

Should I just use url query strings to recall all of the field values and be done with it?  Is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user refreshes the page the whole application is reloaded, so is the data. You could use some [built-in browser storage](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/), like Local Storage, to store the data and load it automagically, when user opens the application.

Comment: but what happened if you gonna clear the localstorage on beforeunload when an user gonna close an app?